# Is mozilla's cross browser addeventlistener shim implementation viable

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, shim

I found this little bit of code over at devloper.Mozilla.
[addEventListener compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener#Compatibility)

Does that code on that page look like it's viable to make addEventListener cross browser?

I don't really have any access to a bunch of old browsers to test it so I thought I'd ask here first.

All new browsers support addEventListener so it's not too big of a deal. I'm just interested in what's available to provide functionality to old browsers and if Mozzilla's shim is worthy.

**I like libraries like jQuery, YUI and prototype, and I know that's an option to make events easier(as it is with all js libraries) so think of this question as academic. For the spirit of learning.**

Comment: http://developer.mozilla.org => our holy grail :D

Comment: It's nice. For a web scripting reference it can't be beat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've linked to looks decent and as far as I know it should work. If I were you however I would start by diving into jQuery source to look for how they are doing it, since jQuery is under constant development, unlike (assuming) example from developer.Mozilla.

*Replace jQuery with any other library you're feeling comfortable with looking into.*

Comment: So it may not be reliable in the long term?

Comment: Nah, it should be good, I'm just saying that you should also look into some code that is carefully crafted and widely used around the Internet. I wouldn't worry about code from mozilla not working on future browsers because it most likely will (I don't know anything about upcoming change in Javascript API regarding events binding).

Comment: One technical thing about mozilla code. It deliberately ignores third attribute that may be normally passed to `addEventListener`. It's done to make the code more cross-browser because some browsers (namely older IEs) don't support binding to capture state of events.

Comment: Oh now I see. No use capture. Can that even be done on old browsers anyway? I could see some complicated simulation of use capture, but it seems like more work than what would be useful. Traversing parents or something maybe. Sorting which nodes' event come first.

Comment: Binding to events in capture phase can be potentially usefull, but given it's not implemented in every browser AND the fact that for years people do crazy stuff without relying on it, you can (I think) skip the support for capture phase (especially if you're going for cross-browser compability). You're right that there are hacks to provide support for capture phase in some browsers, but it's not worth it (unless you're trying to do some really specific stuff).

Comment: Thanks WTK. I think I have my answer without an answer. It might work for a while, but it might need hacking later if some standard or thing is updated. Maybe it's adaptable to some other mechanism like a library plugin or something, but I'm probably gonna stay away from it. Maybe I'll experiment with it when I can get the time. There are some old computers that my friends have. Maybe that could be a testing ground. :)